# Preventing the screen going on on power connection

Tags: power-options

Whenever my phone is connected to the power source the screen goes on, I would really like to disable this feature, but cannot find any relevant option.

In case you want to know why this causes me problems I have disabled automatic screen off and the roads are very bumpy and regardless how many new cables I buy they cannot prevent power cable reconnecting.

HTC U11 Android 9.

Comment: Activate developer options by tapping about phone /build seven times or more and look for something like stay awake and toggle that. See this for developer options activation https://www.htc.com/sea/support/htc-u11/faq/enable-developer-options.html

Comment: I'm afraid it misunderstood my question, I love stay awake feature, that's why I do not want automatic wake up on power connection.

Comment: HTC U11 has AFAIK a USB-C connector. If the usb connection is unstable I would assume that the USB plug on the phone has a loose connection and should be fixed by replacing or soldering.